# An immovable object and an irresistible force

Tags: logic

If an immovable object is an object that cannot be moved no matter what and an irresistible force can move anything, what would happen if an irresistible force is used on the immovable object?

Comment: Why people leve a downvote without an explanation? This is a good startup question. +1 from me

Comment: This is a common question in introductory logic classes. Imagine if a professor laughed the student out of class for bringing it up.

Comment: @Frank , Thank you. My thoughts exactly, I am dumbfounded why it is getting negative marks and getting closed, are the inmates running the lunaticasalyum?

Comment: I haven't laughed when a student brought it up, but I always did groan inside. That said, I actually upvoted it, don't see how it can be thought to be "not a real question," and, while not finding it especially interesting as quickly disposed with for the reasons give by @Paul, also think it is clear, and likely of interest to many with an interest in the site.

Comment: Answer: The universe ends and a even more incomprehensible one takes its place.

Comment: @ichiro, @arjang, @frankcrook, @vanden, @paulcalcraft - I cited this question as incorrectly closed in my answer to [this question on meta](http://meta.philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/127/how-can-we-encourage-asking-questions-and-increase-the-rate-of-new-questions).  Please give it a look.

Comment: @ichiro: This question was closed because it has no context and is based on contradictory premises. As Paul Calcraft writes, it's impossible to have a universe with both something that is unresistable and something that is immovable. This makes the question fall in the category of "not a real question" for all the below items (ambiguity, vagueness, incompleteness, etc.). This is at best Community Wiki material, if indeed this is a common concern on people's minds.

Answer (score 15):

This is an unanswerable question due to **contradictory premises**.

The immovable object vs. the irresistible force question is a commonly used example for this fallacy of reason, and it is explained [on this page](http://www.virtualsalt.com/think/matfall3.htm):

> The problem here is that in a universe
>   where an irresistible force has been
>   defined to exist, there cannot also
>   exist an immovable object, because
>   then the force would not be
>   irresistible. Conversely, if there is
>   discovered or defined such an item as
>   an immovable object, then *by
>   definition* there can be no such thing
>   as an irresistible force.

Comment: That is example of a system with contradicting axioms, not definitions. Things can be defined to anything to begin with but only when put together they become contradictory.

Comment: @Arjang Sorry, I don't quite understand the point you are making. Would you mind rewording or expounding?

Comment: never mind, the wording of this question is better than the vaiations I had seen before and I had them in mind when I was answering this question. A little variation made a big difference.'

Answer (score 2):

It's a fallacy of reason only if you "assume" that the irresistible force and the immovable object are two separate entities. If they are one and the same, then the statement "they can't meet" holds true. Now, if the universe is the irresistible force and the immovable object, then the logic holds.

Comment: @Arjang Again the fallacy of reason. I did say they can't collide because it is only one entity. What I am saying is that they can co exists. The other assumption is that a irresistible force moves.

Comment: I see your point